# Function to return a list node apart of a linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, struct, linked-list

I am working with these two structures, the first holds the employee information while the second holds the list information:

```
typedef struct ListNodeTag{
  int idNumber;
  struct ListNodeTag *next;
} Employee;

typedef Employee Item;

typedef struct {
  int size;
  Item *head;
} List;
```

I have this function called Peek in which I send a position, the head of the list, and a pointer to an element apart of Employee.

```
void Peek (int position, List *L, Item *X) {

  int i;
  Item *currentPtr;

  currentPtr = L->head;

  for(i = 0; i < position; i++){
    if(currentPtr->next == NULL){
      X = currentPtr;
      break;
    }
    currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
  }

  X = currentPtr;

}
```

I call the function Peek from main in this loop.

```
  for(i=0;i<Length(&L);i++){
    Peek(i,&L,&S);
    printf("    %d%\n",idNumber);
  }
```

It's purpose is to print off each member of the list with the Employee ID on a new line.  The first member of the list however, when the second is called, a seg-fault occurs at the line `currentPtr = currentPtr->next;`

The data in my list is populated from this insert function:

```
void Insert (Item X, int position, List *L) {
  int i;
  Item *currentPtr,*previousPtr;
  Item *temp = malloc(sizeof(Item));

  temp->idNumber = X.idNumber;
  temp->next = NULL;

  previousPtr = NULL;

  if(L->head == NULL){
     L->head = temp;
  }

  else{
    currentPtr = L->head;
    for(i=0;i<=position && currentPtr!=NULL;i++){
      previousPtr = currentPtr;
      currentPtr = currentPtr->next;
    }
    temp->next = currentPtr;
    previousPtr->next = temp;
  }
  L->size +=1;
 }
```

Upon printing, I am able to get results without a segfault however, it is the same entry repeated for however long the list is.  EG: for a length of 3 I get:

```
10925
10925
10925
```

Comment: You have a `for` loop going to each `next` position. But you aren't checking to see if you hit a `next` which is NULL. There's a lot of code missing here, though, so it's hard to tell how you've populated your data.

Comment: I have added my insert function for more detail.  If it hits NULL then I suppose it should automatically abort to avoid a seg-fault?

Comment: How would it "automatically" abort? If it references a NULL as the next pointer, it will segfault. So imagine the case where on a loop iteration, the value of `currentPtr->next` is NULL. Then the next value of `currentPtr` becomes NULL by the assignment. Then next time through the loop you attempt, essentially, `NULL->next` which will segfault.

Comment: Oh! I added an if statement `if(currentPtr->next == NULL){break;`} however it seg-faults too.  Could the error lie in the way my next pointers are being set?

Comment: I think you need to show your updated code. I'm not sure where you put that `if`. But something similar may be happening somewhere else. When you are using pointers in C, you have to think through their use very carefully to make sure they're set to what you want when you want them.

Comment: Absolutely I know what you are saying.  I have updated the code along with a sample output I get.

Comment: Your main `for` loop prints the same `idNumber` over and over again but doesn't look like it changes it.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two problems with this code.

---

The first problem is with your `Peek` function. Look at the last line:

```
X = currentPtr;
```

Recall that C is a [call by value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value) language, which means that this line only changes `Peek`'s local value of `X`, which is simply discarded when `Peek` returns; `main` never sees it.

You need to change `Peek` to be something like

```
void Peek (int position, List *L, Item **X) {
```

and then the last line of `Peek` should be changed to

```
*X = currentPtr;
```

Accordingly, you need to change the value that is passed as `X` by `main` into `Peek`. You didn't say how you declared `S` inside your `main` function, but I presume it is currently of the form:

```
Item *S;
```

You then need to change it to

```
Item *S[1];
```

The `Peek` call can be left alone as

```
Peek(i,&L,&S);
```

After these changes, `main` will declare an array `S` of length 1 of `Item` pointers, and will pass the address of `S` to `Peek`. The last line of `Peek` then stores `currentPtr` at the address pointed to by its value of `X`, writing over the first `Item` pointer in the array `S`.

---

The second problem is with the `for` loop:

```
for(i=0;i<Length(&L);i++){
  Peek(i,&L,&S);
  printf("    %d%\n",idNumber);
}
```

Why do you expect the `printf` to print different things on each iteration of the loop? `idNumber` is not being changed at all in the loop! With the (fixed) version of `Peek`, the only thing being changed is the first element of the array `S`, so you need something like `printf("%d\n", S[0]->idNumber);`.

---

You also should remove `X = currentPtr;` from your loop in `Peek`,

```
if(currentPtr->next == NULL){
  X = currentPtr;
  break;
}
```

as it is redundant; the exact same line (in the unmodified `Peek`) is run immediately after the `break` statement.